# Reduce Array of Objects with non-identical (but similar / overlapping) values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Consider the following object:

```
[
  { highlight: "He likes cake", location: "29" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate", location: "29-32" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not", location: "29-31" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate cake", location: "29-34" },
  { highlight: "Jane said Hi.", location: "40" },
  { highlight: "I like her brother, but not her mum", location: "45-50" },
  { highlight: "I liked her brother", location: "45" },
  { highlight: "Some other irrelevant sentence", location: "54" },
  { highlight: "and this is why I liked her!", location: "55-60" },
  { highlight: "Yes, and this is why I liked her!", location: "53-60" },
]
```

It represents highlights of some sort. I'd like to go through this array and whenever the same section was highlighted multiple times, I'd like to remove all *"multiples"* and only keep the last element.

**For example:** These 4 elements in the array all cover more or less the same location:

```
  { highlight: "He likes cake", location: "29" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate", location: "29-32" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not", location: "29-31" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate cake", location: "29-34" },
```

Of those I'd like to *remove all "duplicates"* and *only keep the latest*, leaving me with:

```
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate cake", location: "29-34" },
```

It's of course wrong to speak of duplicates here, since the elements are technically different. And this is precisely where my problem lies. I do not know how to reduce this array.

**Expected output for the array given above:**

```
[
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate cake", location: "29-34" },
  { highlight: "Jane said Hi.", location: "40" },
  { highlight: "I liked her brother, but not her mum.", location: "45-50" },
  { highlight: "Some other irrelevant sentence", location: "54" },
  { highlight: "Yes, and this is why I liked her!", location: "53-60" },
]
```

**Attempt**
I've tried this so far, (based on an answer here), but it only works with identical values:

```
const map = data.reduceRight((r, e) => {
  const key = `${e.highlight}|${e.location}`;
  if (!r.has(key)) r.set(key, e);
  return r;
}, new Map);

const uniq = [...map.values()];
console.log(uniq)
```

edit: changed the example to include locations that have different initial numbers.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that "duplicates" will always be adjacent to each other in the array?

Comment: Oh good question actually. I will say yes now, it's the most likely case and I could live with having a few duplicates if that means the code will be more straightforward & easy to read.

Comment: What do you consider duplicates... overlapping pages or the string

Comment: @DennisVash If locations overlap so will the strings. if strings overlap, location will not necessarily overlap, an author might use a similar phrase twice and the user might also highlight it twice. so it might be better to go for location.

Comment: Please define "*cover more or less the same location*" more rigidly. In the example you gave, all locations started with the same number, is that the criteria you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is defining a similarity function. From the examples you provided, I infer that 2 entries are similar if their `location` ranges overlap. So with this definition of similarity, you can `reduce` the `data` array in the following manner:

```js
var data = [
  { highlight: "He likes cake", location: "29" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate", location: "29-32" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not", location: "29-31" },
  { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate cake", location: "29-34" },
  { highlight: "Jane said Hi.", location: "40" },
  { highlight: "I like her brother, but", location: "45" },
  { highlight: "I liked her brother, but not her mum.", location: "45-50" },
  { highlight: "Some other irrelevant sentence", location: "54" },

];

function areSimilar(h1, h2) {
  const [loc1Start, loc1End] = h1.location.split('-').map(l => parseInt(l));
  const [loc2Start, loc2End] = h2.location.split('-').map(l => parseInt(l));
  return (loc1Start >= loc2Start && loc1Start <= (loc2End || loc2Start)) ||
         ((loc1End || loc1Start) > loc2Start && (loc1End || loc1Start) <= (loc2End || loc2Start));
}

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (areSimilar(curr, acc[acc.length - 1])) acc[acc.length - 1] = curr;
  else acc.push(curr);
  return acc;
}, [data[0]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this works only with the given order. for example, if you move the firts item to bottom, you get this item as well at the end of the result array.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes I had asked the OP if similar entries would be adjacent and they said we can make that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the ranges, if they overlap and take the one with the greater range.

```js
const getRange = s => (s + '-' + s).split('-').slice(0, 2).map(Number);

var array = [{ highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate", location: "29-32" }, { highlight: "He likes cake, but not", location: "29-31" }, { highlight: "He likes cake, but not chocolate cake", location: "29-34" }, { highlight: "Jane said Hi.", location: "40" }, { highlight: "I like her brother, but", location: "45" }, { highlight: "I liked her brother, but not her mum.", location: "45-50" }, { highlight: "Some other irrelevant sentence", location: "54" }, { highlight: "He likes cake", location: "29" }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var [aStart, aEnd] = getRange(o.location),
            bStart, bEnd,
            index = r.findIndex(({ location }) => {
                [bStart, bEnd] = getRange(location);
                return (aStart >= bStart && aEnd <= bEnd || aStart <= bStart && aEnd > bStart || aStart < bEnd && aEnd >= bEnd);
            });
        if (index === -1) {
            r.push(o);
        } else {
            if (aStart <= bStart && aEnd >= bEnd) r[index] = o;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: but this assumes that the longer range will be the correct one, not the one occurring in the array last, correct? admittedly, in the given example these two cases happen to coincide, but that mustn't always be so.